# "Access is denied" javascript error for all deployed images on java web app generated html page

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have an old java web app that generates HTML pages deployed via an EAR/WAR file running on a JBoss application server. The app and environment has been deployed for some time and has not changed lately. Everything was fine.

Within the last few weeks, many users are reporting that images are no longer being displayed. After turning on script debugging in MS Internet Explorer I can see that it is reporting a javascript error "Access is denied" in the IMG tag within HTML anchors that contain image file references to the image folder within the deployment file. The script debugger shows:

The file exists in the images folder in the context path. This is happening to the majority of users with different Windows and Explorer versions, but not all.

Any ideas on where to turn would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: > <a ... <img... on... "this.src='images\\xxxx.xxx';" x Access is denied. ></a>

Comment: Upon further review, the application works and displays all images properly in Chrome which seems to prove that everything is set up properly on the server side. Unfortunately, this is not an option due to a lot of IE specific scripting.

Comment: ><img border='0'  src='images\topbanner_logo.jpg'> Image files that are referenced in vanilla img tags do not display at all and do not throw any errors.

Comment: > <td align='left' background='images\topbanner_gradient.jpg' >width='90%' style='background-repeat:repeat-y' valign='middle'  >bgcolor='#184FB4'>  Strangely, images referenced in a table cell background tag, do display properly.

Comment: > <a href="#" tabindex="-1" onclick="javascript:CalendarPopup_select(document.forms[0].ffRCVD_DATE_1,event,'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a'); event.cancelBubble=true;" name="DateSelectffRCVD_DATE_1">
<img  width="21" height="21" alt="Select Date" src="images\calendar.gif" style="border: 0;" onmousedown="this.src='images\\calendarpressed.gif';" onmouseup="this.src='images\\calendarselected.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='images\\calendar.gif';"></a> ... The image file in the img src tag does not display. Triggering any of the onmouse events throws the Access is denied script error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved by installing the March 2019 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 8.1. Internet Explorer version 11.0.9600.19301 – Update versions: 11.0.115 (KB4489873) is displaying all images properly now.